# What is a good resource for HTML character codes -> glyph and

Tags: html, character-encoding, special-characters, glyph

I've already found a good site to convert HTML character codes to their respective glyphs:

http://www.public.asu.edu/~rjansen/glyph_encoding.html

However, I need a bit more information. Does anyone know of a site like the one above that also provides information on what type of character code it is? Meaning, is it a special character? Is the glyph visible? Etc...

So far I have found some tables with this information, but they aren't as complete as the resource above. I would really like to get my hands on a complete table.

Thanks,
-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML Entity Character Lookup](http://leftlogic.com/lounge/articles/entity-lookup/)

Comment: I riffed on this and added a larger Unicode set and a responsive mobile version. I call it [&what;](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/)

Answer (score 1):

I like FileFormat.Info--e.g.: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20ac/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

The character map on Ubuntu (and I assume most other Linux distros) is fantastic. You can search for any character by its name or description (e.g. "arrow") really easily.

Windows' character map is a poor imitation but kinda works too. It seems to decide that certain fonts (Arial, Verdana etc) can't display some characters, even though they work absolutely fine. (Hint: try MS's more recent font creations like Calibri for better results.)

Once you've found a character you can either:

- Copy it and use it directly (requires pages to be UTF-8) like this: ↗
- Insert it as a hexadecimal entity. The above character is "U+2197 North East Arrow" so the entity would be `&#x2197;`
- Convert the hex code to decimal (the calculators on Windows and Linux can do this). The above example is `&#8599;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick, low-footprint way to look them up: [&what;](http://ndpsoftware.com/&what/)